# React-native google/facebook login authentication on server

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, google-signin

App Structure: `react-native` app and `restify` backend.

**Idea:**

1. User presses on login(can be google or facebook) goes to app(fb or shows google accounts) or browser and asks for username/password and permission.
2. Goes back to our app the result should be **one-time token(auth code)**
3. App sends **auth code** to backend `/api/oauth`
4. Backend calls the provider exchange the one-time token with the access token - here backend creates user
5. Backend creates **JWT** and gives a response to the app
6. Now app can access to authorized apis with `Authorization` header

Using `react-native-fbsdk` for facebook, `@react-native-community/google-signin` for google sign in.

Google sign in offers `offlineAccess` property when configuring and it requires `webClientId` which is a backend URL for development it is now http://localhost:8000. But it gives error no `webClientId` is declared.

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: process.env.GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
      androidClientId: process.env.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
      iosClientId: process.env.IOS_CLIENT_ID,
      offlineAccess: true,
    });
```

For facebook could not find any guide. Now both of them are just directly returning the profile and `access_token`.

**Question:**

Is there any better approach than mentioned above?

How to do the backend authentication?

**Note:**

Gone through lots of tutorials which usually suggest using Firebase.

Is it really necessary?

Comment: wat do you want again to cross verify if the user of fb and google is real?

Comment: mitigate man-in-the-middle-attacks